# Injection or creating instance with new()

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I'm a C# programmer and I'm thinking about dependency injection. I've read ["Dependency injection in .NET"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182501) book and patterns and antipatterns of DI are quite clear for me. I use pattern `injection in constructor` most of the time. Are there any cases in wich it is preferrable to create instances directly rather than using a Dependency Injection framework?

Comment: You can still use `new(). Depends on *where* you use it.That aside, answers to this question will likely just be opinions. There are not strict rules, and without any scale or context for your application, it's hard to even give a good advice.

Comment: This article might be helpful: http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/

Comment: I edited the answer to answer more directly, hoping this is enough for you and it can be accepted :)

Comment: Also changed the question, feel free to re-edit to make it more suitable to your problem, try to not ask generic things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Dependency Injection has the advantage of making code **Testable**, however abusing DI pattern makes code harder to understand. Take in example [this framework](https://github.com/elvman/ouzel/blob/master/ouzel/Animator.cpp) (ouzel, I'm not affiliated in any way. I just liked the way it was designed) wich I started recently to follow, as you see most classes have dependencies injected, however there is still a single instance shared without constructor injection `sharedEngine`.

In that particular case I find the author did a good choice, that makes the code overall simpler to understand (simpler constructors, less members) and eventually more performant (you don't have a shared pointer stored in every instance of every class of the engine).

Still its code can be tested because you can replace that instance (global) with a mock (the worst point of globals is that initialization order and their dependencies are hard to track, however if you limit to few globals with no or few dependencies this is not a problem). As you see you are not always forced to inject everything from constructor (and I wrote a DI injection framework for C++).

The problem is that people think is always good injectin everything from constructor so you suddendly start seeing frameworks that allow to inject everything (like `int` or `std::vector<float>`) while in reality that's the worst idea ever (infact in my simple framework I allow just to inject classes) since code becomes harder to understand because you are mixing configuration values with logic configuration and you have to travel through more files to get a grasp of what code is doing.

So, constructor injection is very good, use it when it is proper, but it is not the Jack-of-all-trades like everything in programming you have to not abuse it. Best of all try to understand good examples of every programming practice/pattern and then roll your own recipe, programming is made of choices, and every choice have good and bad sides.

**When is it Ok (and by "OK" I mean you will still be able to test the code, as it were not coupled to concrete instances) to call "new":**

- **You need Polymorphis**, most times it is easier to create the new class than configuring that using a DI framework
- **You need a object factory**, usually the factory itself is injected, however the factory code call "new" explicitly
- You are calling **"new" in the main**
- The object you are creating with "new" **has no dependencies**, and thus using it inside a class does not make the class harder to test (in example you create **standard .NET containers** with new, doing otherwise results in much more confusion)
- The object you are creating is a **global instance** wich do not rely on order of initialization and its dependencies are not visible otherelse (you can mock the instance as long as you access it through a interface).

The above list provide situations in wich even when using a DI framework (like Ninject) it is ok to call "new" without removing the possibility to test your code, even better, most times you use DI in the above cases you usually end up with more complex code.